# Display an unordered list of phone numbers

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I made a block to loop though the database and grab all the numbers and display them on an unordered list but they are all coming back on the same line like they are all one item. I feel that the block should automatically separate them? [image]

```
`<h1>Listing Numbers</h1>
  <div class='from-group'>
    <ul>
      <li class="numbers">
        <% @people.each do |person| %>
          <%= person.phone_number %>
        <% end %>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
`
```

Comment: I don't believe I have any CSS yet.

Comment: Thanks Dude! Had a brainless moment there. If you post that as an answer I'll check it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I think is happening is that **all** the numbers are on ONE `li` rather than individual `li`...

See the difference:

```html
<h1>Listing Numbers</h1>
<div class='from-group'>
  <ul>
    <li class="numbers">
      Item 1 Item 2 Item 3 (we're all in the same li)
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>

<h1>Listing Numbers</h1>
<div class='from-group'>
  <ul>
    <li class="numbers">Item 1 Separate li</li>
    <li class="numbers">Item 2 Separate li</li>
    <li class="numbers">Item 3 Separate li</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's one iteration only and `person.phone_number` prints all three numbers at once. Check the `person`. I think it holds all three numbers in one attribute `phone_number`. In this case you could split the numbers and join them together with a html line break.

```
<%= person.phone_number.split(" ").join("<br />") %>
```

But with this solution you keep the numbers in one `li` element only.

The other way would be to think about a database migration to store the numbers within different attributes (phone, mobil, fax, ...).